# Relative Path in Web.config When DataBase not inside the App_Data

Tags: asp.net, web-config

How I can get relative path for ConnectionSetting   Web.config in my web site

When DataBase Not inside the App_Data Folder

I try to use This

```
~/dataBase/mydatabase.mdf..................
```

But not Work

any help please

Answer (score 0):

You can change the path that your [`|DataDirectory|`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254504.aspx) points to by setting it through [`AppDomain.SetData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37z40s1c.aspx):

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", myNewDataDirectory);
```